# Access port config

Tags: cisco-catalyst

Having read several of the posts here on access port commands, I'm wondering if I have created myself an issue.  I've been running my current MDF config for some time without problems.  I'm trying to add in another switch (same model-Cisco 3850x) from another closet.  I've got a fiber connection between the MDF stack and the new switch.  As soon as I connect them, I lose connectivity to my VoIP server (runs on VLAN10).  I have several IDF switches without this problem (Cisco 3750 model) and the configs are the same.  Not sure why it shuts down traffic to the VoIP server, however the phones continue to work so I don't think it is blocking all VLAN10 traffic.  Thus I started looking at the port that the VoIP server is connected to in the MDF switch.  The config is:

```
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 10
 no mdix auto
 spanning-tree portfast
```

Could this trouble be due to having 3 switchport commands in the config?  If so, why has it not been an issue so far?  Please advise. Thank you!

```
Switch Configs below:
```

MDF SWITCH CONFIG

```
version 15.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
service compress-config
service unsupported-transceiver
!
hostname ABC_MDF3850X
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-vrf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
enable secret 4 U5rt3dNsFEwpQKnq.KtUefCn3IvPiEFtMOmdsxOsuRc
!
username admin secret 4 U5rt3dNsFEwpQKnq.KtUefCn3IvPiEFtMOmdsxOsuRc
no aaa new-model
clock timezone CST -6 0
clock summer-time CDST recurring
switch 1 provision ws-c3850-48p
switch 2 provision ws-c3850-48p
ip routing
!
ip domain-name ABC.com
ip device tracking
!
!
qos wireless-default-untrust
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-1662411534
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-1662411534
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-1662411534
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-1662411534
 certificate self-signed 01
  3082024F 308201B8 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050030 
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 31363632 34313135 3334301E 170D3136 30333238 31333030 
  30315A17 0D323030 31303130 30303030 305A3031 312F302D 06035504 03132649 
  4F532D53 656C662D 5369676E 65642D43 65727469 66696361 74652D31 36363234 
  31313533 3430819F 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 01050003 818D0030 81890281 
  8100A8D8 FF90427E AA7DE7E5 1AF8BE7D E7828B52 4232AAE5 6DC2234A 57579337 
  EAB91429 AF3F275A F5D7715B 3D82E19E DE953A7A DF6512CF 40090F7D 1CA264B6 
  E1A2207D 83CED72F 3DB976EB 2D2BB1FD 57D5AE64 A71D2648 A581BF1A 5F32BFCB 
  E3761379 2ED2DB6F E2C9C1DE 5A289A72 B6BAA4A2 095D8E72 F5616888 8F43FFEB 
  0C070203 010001A3 77307530 0F060355 1D130101 FF040530 030101FF 30220603 
  551D1104 1B301982 174C4456 5F4D4446 33383530 582E6C64 76757361 2E636F6D 
  301F0603 551D2304 18301680 144B5ED2 177490FF C50E4F1A 77C3297E 4FA8641D 
  AA301D06 03551D0E 04160414 4B5ED217 7490FFC5 0E4F1A77 C3297E4F A8641DAA 
  300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 04050003 81810091 B8681A44 5654D68B 11C50EC1 
  80341321 04D34B87 3429F0BD 8D0DBF8B 7BE423F0 B2A12BAA 7E7621E2 58FB1257 
  23641DAF 477326DC 9740D743 33C0AD03 89326569 9B6E0FB9 3899FA24 5924AAD9 
  8B201692 2B60FBB0 B196A474 C7FC8C6A 620C4307 95283DCA A9CD1067 937EEF83 
  EF72CA02 81CE0A47 CF725BBF 215F2080 B403CE
 quit
!
!
diagnostic bootup level minimal
identity policy webauth-global-inactive
 inactivity-timer 3600 
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
redundancy
 mode sso
!
!
class-map match-any non-client-nrt-class
  match non-client-nrt 
!
policy-map port_child_policy
 class non-client-nrt-class
    bandwidth remaining ratio 10
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 no ip address
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description  
 switchport access vlan 5
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 10
 no mdix auto
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
(Ports 1/0/2 - 48 have been removed to save space)
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
 description Trunk to 1st Fl South
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
 description Trunk to 1st Fl South
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
 description Trunk to New Parts
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
 description Trunk to Wireless
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/1
 description 
 switchport access vlan 5
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 10
 no mdix auto
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/2
(Ports 2/0/2 - 31 removed to save space)
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/32
 description VoIP server
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 10
 no mdix auto
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/33
 description VoIP backup server
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 10
 no mdix auto
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/34
(Ports 2/0/35 - 48 removed to save space)
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/1
 description Trunk to Fiber
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/2
 description Trunk to Warehouse
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/3
 description Trunk to Gappa
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/1/4
 description Trunk to Motorola Wifi
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet2/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
 description Management VLAN
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan5
 description Data VLAN
 ip address 10.0.70.1 255.255.254.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
interface Vlan10
 description Voice VLAN
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
interface Vlan15
 description Gappa VLAN
 ip address 10.10.50.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.71.254 name Sonicwall-FW
!
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
line vty 5 15
 login
!
ntp server 128.105.39.11 prefer
ntp server 130.126.24.24
ntp server 198.82.1.201
ntp server 68.77.126.250
wsma agent exec
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
wsma agent config
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
wsma agent filesys
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
wsma agent notify
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma profile listener httplistener
 transport http
!
wsma profile listener httpslistener
 transport https
ap dot11 24ghz rrm channel dca 1
ap dot11 24ghz rrm channel dca 6
ap dot11 24ghz rrm channel dca 11
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 36
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 40
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 44
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 48
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 52
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 56
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 60
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 64
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 149
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 153
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 157
ap dot11 5ghz rrm channel dca 161
ap group default-group
end
```

PARTS SWITCH CONFIG

```
!
version 15.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime localtime
service timestamps log datetime localtime
service password-encryption
service compress-config
!
hostname ABC-3850PARTS
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
vrf definition Mgmt-vrf
 !
 address-family ipv4
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv6
 exit-address-family
!
enable secret 5 $1$M.jF$TEYgV2toHpb/y7Rl9cBIX1
enable password 7 00171105565808551C32
!
username admin privilege 15 password 7 0518040C734F4D5A0A16
no aaa new-model
clock timezone CST -6 0
clock summer-time CDST recurring
switch 1 provision ws-c3850-48p
!
!
ip domain-name ABC.com
!
!
qos queue-softmax-multiplier 100
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-1439475857
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-1439475857
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-1439475857
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-1439475857
 certificate self-signed 01
  3082022B 30820194 A0030201 02020101 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 05050030 
  31312F30 2D060355 04031326 494F532D 53656C66 2D536967 6E65642D 43657274 
  69666963 6174652D 31343339 34373538 3537301E 170D3137 31303230 31363534 
  35315A17 0D323030 31303130 30303030 305A3031 312F302D 06035504 03132649 
  4F532D53 656C662D 5369676E 65642D43 65727469 66696361 74652D31 34333934 
  37353835 3730819F 300D0609 2A864886 F70D0101 01050003 818D0030 81890281 
  8100BAA8 C3AD16F2 032BAABA EBF947DB 3E8D1489 517B3613 3CE51072 763EA4F9 
  C01B4916 4BC3DF15 491EDAFA F62C89EF 109E75AF 970D41D5 2EE32398 F564B82F 
  37FE089E 239ACAB1 B6C58271 5CF8418D 9B6D02ED 6D7421AB AE12E5E2 BD68D7B2 
  71E018EA DBAE8898 146FBA17 AC070F26 F1575842 6AD00506 0C5C7EE2 8B7FA0EF 
  9F910203 010001A3 53305130 0F060355 1D130101 FF040530 030101FF 301F0603 
  551D2304 18301680 14F2CB4F 28019962 27BC5F00 1F4B60A8 C318CAC3 E6301D06 
  03551D0E 04160414 F2CB4F28 01996227 BC5F001F 4B60A8C3 18CAC3E6 300D0609 
  2A864886 F70D0101 05050003 8181006E BC751E4D 83BD0561 710837AB F51710DA 
  700B2F50 B6DAC537 D93D0548 9B505E76 710DAC43 AF1540D7 7DD38DE3 5AECCCC2 
  CDE5EE8D EDCDA81E D0E9E59C A9E3DA9A 57B048BC 992D7EA3 DA2D8BCC 0618B479 
  D9F90FA8 08B19483 C2EFA183 F8B8C160 BAEEBE94 66622195 5D32D813 B427FB09 
  EA57A906 7B69D09C 4623D201 9EFC53
    quit
diagnostic bootup level minimal
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
hw-switch switch 1 logging onboard message level 3
!
redundancy
 mode sso
!
!class-map match-any non-client-nrt-class
!
policy-map port_child_policy
 class non-client-nrt-class
  bandwidth remaining ratio 10
!
! 
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 vrf forwarding Mgmt-vrf
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 switchport access vlan 5
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 10
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
(Ports 1/0/2 - 1/0/48 removed to save space)
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/1
 description Trunk to MDF
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/2
 description Trunk to Krift
 switchport trunk native vlan 5
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,10,15
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/3
 description Trunk connection 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1/4
 description Trunk connection
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/1
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/2
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/3
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/4
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.0.0.6 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan5
 description Data VLAN
 ip address 10.0.70.1 255.255.254.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
interface Vlan10
 description Voice VLAN
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
interface Vlan15
 description Gappa VLAN
 ip address 10.10.50.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
ip default-gateway 10.0.0.1
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
!
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 password 7 0215065859050C725F5D
 login
 length 0
line vty 5 15
 password 7 0215065859050C725F5D
 no login
!
ntp server 10.0.0.1
wsma agent exec
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent config
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
wsma agent filesys
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
 profile http
 profile httpliste
!
wsma agent notify
 profile httplistener
 profile httpslistener
!
!
 wsma profile listener httplistener
 transport http
!
wsma profile listener httpslistener
 transport https
!
ap group default-group
end
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include a good description of how the network devices are connected and their configurations. We cannot simply guess what is wrong.

Comment: The answer to your specific question is No.   As @ronmaupin says, you need to post a diagram and the configurations of both switches.  One possibility (admittedly a guess) is an IP address conflict.  But we need to see the configs to tell.

Comment: I have a stack of (2) 3850 switches in my MDF.  The new 3850 switch has a fiber connection between it and a trunk port in the MDF stack.  Is there a way for me to attach a txt file of the configs?

Comment: Simply edit the question, paste in the configurations, and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an IP address conflict.  Both switches have the same IP address on interface VLAN 10.

MDF:

```
interface Vlan10
 description Voice VLAN
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
```

Parts:

```
interface Vlan10
 description Voice VLAN
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip helper-address 10.0.70.2
!
```

If they're trunked together, you don't need an IP address on both switches on the VLAN interface.  One is enough.  For example, you can modify the Parts switch like this:

```
interface Vlan 10
no ip address
```

Comment: Thank you, I did just find the address conflict in the output of show log.  With that said, should I make those changes for all of the VLANs listed although only this one is throwing an error?

Comment: Yes, you only need one gateway address, and you should never have duplicate IP addresses anywhere in your network.

Comment: If this answer helps you, please consider accepting it so this question doesn't keep popping up in the list, looking for an answer.

Comment: It did the trick.  Thank you for your help!  I've learned something new today and I appreciate that very much.  Have a great day!